# How to export orders in CSV file in Magento 2

Tags: magento2

In Magento 2.2, I am creating a module to export orders in CSV file, please anybody can help me into this. Please suggest what is the correct way to export orders in CSV file.

Also, anyone know that how can I get orders column name like `order_id`, `firstname`, `lastname` etc.

Comment: Could you indicate what you have tried so far?

Comment: Hi Kzrystof, i just started creating module and i need only a way to export orders, please help me

Comment: please anybody help me

Comment: anybody know about it ?

Comment: Are you looking for a complete source code or just a direction and btw the question is not clear as well. You just want to extend the sales order export module or want to create a new custom module. If so, then what's the purpose of it. Well, if you just want to add some additional fields then you can use plugins [Order export](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/225276/magento-2-sales-order-grid-custom-column-export-csv-issue?noredirect=1&lq=1). Otherwise, have a look into Magento 2 Sales Order Module.